# go lang http server 503 error with load

Tags: go

I wrote the below GO program for a purpose test. This http server receives get request and makes a http call to another rest service. This program works fine but when I run a load test in 2vCPUs 8 GB box. It started giving Http 503 after around 500 TPS.

```
func retrievedata(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 5,
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                InsecureSkipVerify: true,
            },
        },
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    urlstring, _ := url.Parse("https://service.dot.com/backendservice/")

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", endpointurl, nil)
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()


    switch resp.StatusCode {
    case 200:

        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        w.Write(data)
    case 404:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        w.Write(data)
    case 500:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        w.Write(data)
    default:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
    }

}


func main() {
    fmt.Println("this is a main function")
    http.HandleFunc("/getdata", retrievedata)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8191", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Service is Running at port 8191")
}
```

I then added go routine to spawn the handler function

```
go http.HandleFunc("/getdata", retrievedata)
```

this time I see a slight increase in the TPS but still I get 503 errors after around 600 TPS. Please note that the other rest function has been tested for 2000TPS so I am sure there is no problem with that.
Should I do anything different to achieve more TPS?

Comment: I recommend to unhide all the errors and write them. Could you check resources: open files, sockets and so on? Next try to use https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/ to look for CPU and memory profile.

Comment: `go http.HandleFunc` is not a good idea. The http server already handles each request in a separate goroutine, and calling `go http.HandleFunc` doesn't even do that--all that does is start a goroutine during the startup phase, which will exit immediately. In short: that goroutine adds exactly nothing (except possibly a race condition during startup)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [transport.go](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go) you'll see:

```
var DefaultTransport RoundTripper = &Transport{
    //... 
    MaxIdleConns:          100,
    IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
    //... 
}

// DefaultMaxIdleConnsPerHost is the default value of Transport's
// MaxIdleConnsPerHost.
const DefaultMaxIdleConnsPerHost = 2
```

When it does `MaxIdleConns: 100` it is setting the size of the connection pool to 100 connections, but `DefaultMaxIdleConnsPerHost` sets it to 2 per host.

So essentially, your connection pool can only hold 2 sockets. So if you were to do 100 concurrent requests, once they finish, 2 of the sockets will remain open in the pool, and the other 98 will be closed and end up in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

Since this is happening in a goroutine in a load testing tool, you will just accumulate thousands of connections in the `TIME_WAIT` state. Eventually, you will run out of ephemeral ports and not be able to open new client connections.

```
defaultRoundTripper := http.DefaultTransport
defaultTransportPtr, ok := defaultRoundTripper.(*http.Transport)
if !ok {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("defaultRoundTripper not an *http.Transport"))
}
defaultTransport := *defaultTransportPtr 
defaultTransport.MaxIdleConns = 1000
defaultTransport.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 1000

client = &http.Client{Transport: &defaultTransport}
```

On top of that, a lot of the work you are doing, you don't need to do on every request.  You could do it more like this:

```
var client *http.Client
var endpointurl string
var req http.Request

func init() {   
    defaultRoundTripper := http.DefaultTransport
    defaultTransportPtr, ok := defaultRoundTripper.(*http.Transport)
    if !ok {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("defaultRoundTripper not an *http.Transport"))
    }
    defaultTransport := *defaultTransportPtr 
    defaultTransport.MaxIdleConns = 1000
    defaultTransport.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 1000
    defaultTransport.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }
    client = &http.Client{Transport: }
    client = &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 5,
        Transport: &defaultTransport
    }
    endpointurl, _ = url.Parse("https://service.dot.com/backendservice/")
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", endpointurl, nil)
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
}

func retrievedata(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    switch resp.StatusCode {
    case 200:
        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        w.Write(data)
    case 404:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        w.Write(data)
    case 500:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        w.Write(data)
    default:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
    }

}


func main() {
    fmt.Println("this is a main function")
    http.HandleFunc("/getdata", retrievedata)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8191", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Service is Running at port 8191")
}
```